# Missing crash in crashlytics after dsym upload

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

The issue is quite simple actually, i've been stuck a long time on missing dsym, it seems the dsym used to prepare the build for testflight are of no use.

Importing them also resulted on crashes to disappear.
Any way to get those crashes back? Obviously i need to debug them as fast as possible before launch which i cannot do if i have no idea where to look.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Actually support helped me get them.
It seems you can actually see those missing crashes with the proper search parameters, it was a pain though.